# Redirect to user's web application login url on Jasper server's session time out

Tags: spring, session, jasperserver

I am embedding my Web application reports with tibco-jasper soft version 6 and above server. My users will access their reports from web application by clicking on a link which is provided in web application. There will be separate token validation done for user login from web application to jasper server. I have configured same time for session. When jasper server session's time out, it is getting redirected to jasper's login page. But I just want to redirect that into my custom url (e.g. My web application's login page).

What i can do now? I am new to jasper.

Comment: What have you done so far? With no self-effort nobody is willing to help you.

Comment: I have tried to by adding bean in my custom xml file called applicationContext-externalAuth-preAuth-mt.xml.  Below line i have added   
 <bean id="externalAuthPropertiesBean" class="com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.security.externalAuth.ExternalAuthProperties">
  <!-- external logout url. If specified, logout will redirect to that address. -->
        <property name="externalLoginUrl" value="http://localhost/login.html"/>
</bean> i dont knw whre to link this bean. so that when session expires,it will be calling this url and redirect it to the same.

Comment: And also i just want to know where this session handling is done exactly like jar and jsp file in tibco jasper server 6.2.

Comment: There is jsp file called externalLogin.jsp in the following location.   C:\Jaspersoft\jasperreports-server-6.2.0\apache-tomcat\webapps\jasperserver-pro\WEB-INF\jsp\modules\login.. we are calling bean configured in xml over here. But my doubt is where to call this jsp file.

Answer (score 0):

In WEB-INF/jsp/modules/login/login.jsp add this to the top of the file:

```
<script>
   if (window.top != window.self) {
      window.parent.location = <your-application-url>;
   }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your update. I have tried in this way by adding above script in login.jsp file. But, It is not working.